# BitWasp Installation Problem

Tags: php, library, bitwasp

I just uploaded the [`BitWasp` code](https://github.com/Bit-Wasp/BitWasp) into `/var/www` but when I tried to install using extension `BitWasp-master/install/index.php` the installation page that I need to make `config.php`, `database.php`, and `bitcoin.php` files writable. And when done I should press F5.

How do I make these files writeable? I don't have permissions to view the contents of those files.

Please help! Thank you

Comment: http://www.seas.upenn.edu/cets/answers/chmod.html

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you need to change permissions on those files:

```
$ chown apache config.php database.php bitcoin.php
$ chmod g+w config.php database.php bitcoin.php
```

Of course, if you're not using apache or the groupid of the webserver you're using is different, you might need to change "apache" to something else.

Read up on [linux file permissions](http://www.linuxclues.com/articles/16.htm) to understand this stuff better.

Answer (score 0):

did you fix it just become root in your terminal and do all the stuff it says. what do you do after pressing F5 ?

also "apt-get install php5-gmp"

add to  /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini >> extension=php_gmp.so